# Ping an external server automatically every 30 mins

Tags: java, jsp, networking, network-programming

I have a set of servers in a list. I want to ping these servers every 30 mins.How can I achieve this.it's a jsp program with java code.

Comment: You can't do a "real ping" (ie, an ICMP echo request) in Java unless you use native code or an external process...

Comment: Using threads can't we do it

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP asks us to write code for him/her.

Answer (score 1):

this code will execute after every 30 mins to pings to the given ip

```
    public boolean ping(String ip) throws IOException, InterruptedException  extends TimerTask {
     public void run{       
     boolean isWindows = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("win");

            ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("ping", isWindows? "-n" : "-c", "1", ip`enter code here`);
            Process proc = processBuilder.start();
            BufferedReader in =
        new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
        while (true) {
        String line = in.readLine();
        if (line == null)
        break;
        if(line.contains("Destination host unreachable")||line.contains("Request timed out")){

            return false;
            }
        }

            return true;
}

        }
// And From your main() method or any other method
Timer timer = new Timer();
 timer.schedule(new ping(ip), 0, (60*30*1000));
```

Comment: I have to manually run to ping...o this code will automatically ping after 30 mins

Comment: above code is for manual , to ping to the server but it may be done by  thread to execute after 30 min.

Comment: How to writ a code using thread

Comment: hey man , just read how to use thread , its not possible to give whole code.

Comment: That, or apply a proper timing facility like Quartz that handles the threading for you.